# Add text on skills bar

Tags: tikz-styles

I would like to add text (centered, or aligned to right) to the skills bar defined as follow:

```
\definecolor{bar100}{RGB}{230,230,250}
\definecolor{bar}{RGB}{147,112,219}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill [bar100] (0,0) rectangle (4,.2);
    \fill [bar] (0,0) rectangle (3.2,.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I found that text can be added using

```
node[pos=1]{8/10}
```

but when I try sth like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill [bar100] (0,0) rectangle (4,.2) node[pos=1]{8/10};
    \fill [bar] (0,0) rectangle (3.2,.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

it doesn't look well.

Could you please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to adjust the size and position of the node. As you put it, the center of the node will be placed at the upper right corner of the bar. This is of course not what you want (as I assume). Try:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{bar100}{RGB}{230,230,250}
\definecolor{bar}{RGB}{147,112,219}

\begin{document}\tiny

\tikzset{barnode/.append style={text height=(.2cm-2.5pt),text depth=.5pt,
  inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt,align=right,anchor=north east,
  black},
  barnode at center/.append style={barnode,text width=(4cm-2pt),align=center}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [bar100] (0,0) rectangle (4,.2) node[barnode]{8/10}; 
    % will be hidden if bar is 9/10 or 10/10
  \fill [bar] (0,0) rectangle (3.2,.2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [bar100] (0,0) rectangle (4,.2) coordinate (a);
  \fill [bar] (0,0) rectangle (3.2,.2);
  \node [barnode] at (a) {8/10};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [bar100] (0,0) rectangle (4,.2) coordinate (b);
  \fill [bar] (0,0) rectangle (3.2,.2);
  \node [barnode at center] at (b) {8/10};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Note that the `pos` option only makes sense if you put the node on a path, like in `\draw (0,0) -- node[pos=.75] {foo} (0,3);`, where `pos` denotes the position of the node on the path, 0 being at the very start, 1 at the very end of this path.

Note that, if you append the node to the first bar, the second bar may cover the text of the node. Hence, better reference to this point using a coordinate. Or just put another node with the same size of the 100% bar after both bars.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will test it. Do you maybe also have any idea how to put the score text centered?

Comment: @kpater87 centered where? if for example you mean centered to the whole (10/10) rectangle in case of score 5/10 it will be ugly... The only way to have a bar like this for all possible numbers is to have the text-score right, left, above or below the (whole) bar. Try 9/10 here and see what I mean.

Comment: Maybe you are right... I will go for text on the right. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @kpater87 Also, if you put it like this, the text may be hidden in case the bar has 9/10 or 10/10. See my edit.

Answer (score 3):

different approach: define node with variable width gives shorter code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{bar100}{RGB}{230,230,250}
\definecolor{bar}{RGB}{147,112,219}
\tikzset{
barnode/.style args = {#1/#2}{
    minimum width=#1, fill=#2, minimum height=2mm,
    text width =\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
    inner xsep=1pt, inner ysep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, font=\tiny, text=black, align=left,
    right}
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node [barnode= 4mm/bar]    at (0.0,0) {};
\node [barnode=36mm/bar100] at (0.4,0) {1/10};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node [barnode=32mm/bar]    at (0.0,0) {};
\node [barnode= 8mm/bar100] at (3.2,0) {8/10};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node [barnode=40mm/bar]    at (0.0,0) {};
\node [barnode= 0mm/bar100] at (4.0,0) {10/10};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]